# What will the following code regarding arrays print?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am confused by a recent test regarding JS arrays. I chose "5" as an answer, but was incorrect. Can someone explain to why "6" is the correct answer to the following code? Thanks for helping a noob out!

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(arr.length + arr[2]);
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                 +--- arr[2]
                 |
                 v 
let arr = [1, 2, 3]; <------ arr.length = 3
console.log(arr.length + arr[2]);
                             ^
                             |
                             +-- arr at index 2 returns 3
```

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]; //arr.length = 3
console.log(arr.length + arr[2]); // arr[2] = 3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(arr[0]);//1
console.log(arr[1]);//2
console.log(arr[2]);//3
```

Array index starts with 0 , so at index 2 , its value is 3

arr length is 3, so you are getting 3 +3 = 6

Answer (score 3):

The length of the array to begin with is 3. Then you access the the element at index 2, which is 3 (because we start counting from 0 rather than 1). Add them together to get 6.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero indexed in JavaScript. Values of arr are as follows:

```
arr[0] == 1
arr[1] == 2
arr[2] == 3
```

So in your example the value of arr[2] is the 3rd item in the array or '3'.

The answer is 6 because arr.length = 3 and arr[2] = 3, and 3 + 3 = 6.

Answer (score 1):

Because the javascript array index starts from 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because :

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arr.length) // 3 

//index start from 0
console.log(arr[0]) // 1
console.log(arr[1]) // 2 
console.log(arr[2]) // 3
```